# Google Play Pre-launch Report crash for all Android 6.0+ devices

Tags: java, android, firebase-test-lab

Anyone getting Google Play Store pre-launch report crashes? We are for our app which runs fine on all our test devices. We are also getting Non-SDK API errors but they're all in support library version 27.1.1 and we can't upgrade to Support library 28.0.0 or AndroidX. It ran fine a couple of days ago now every test device on the pre-launch report running >API 19 crashes at the start. We have no custom `ParcelableSpans`. What's happening?

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "int android.text.ParcelableSpan.getSpanTypeIdInternal()"
    at android.text.TextUtils.writeToParcel(TextUtils.java:653)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeCharSequence(Parcel.java:576)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1362)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:759)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.writeAccessibilityRecordToParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1173)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEvent.writeToParcel(AccessibilityEvent.java:1139)
    at android.view.accessibility.IAccessibilityManager$Stub$Proxy.sendAccessibilityEvent(IAccessibilityManager.java:233)
    at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityManager.java:320)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6426)
    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:5842)
    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:5821)
    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:5798)
    at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEvent(View.java:5765)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.sendAccessibilityEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2517)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3414)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5459)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

`build.gradle`

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    ...
  }
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues and solved it by adding the following  directive to the `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```java
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.text.ParcelableSpan {
  public int getSpanTypeIdInternal();
  public void writeToParcelInternal(android.os.Parcel, int);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend asking these specific questions to the #test-lab channel on the Firebase community on Slack. It would be best if you could even provide the exact details on which tests failed, as the devs can look at your case directly.